# combinations: given K stars and L squares, how many ways can you choose a subset with at least one square

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Here's my problem:  The post office has 15 types of stamps and only 2 of them are royals.  If I purchase 3 stamps, how many ways can I come home with at least 1 royal stamp?

The answer I was given is 325 ways.  I can't figure out how to get that.

I thought, find out how many ways to get any 3 stamps from 15, then subtract from that the number of ways to get 3 non-royal stamps from 13, but that gives an answer of 169. Somebody please help!

Comment: Given the numbers in the problem as you have written, I agree with the answer of $169$.  Check to make sure that the problem is written correctly and check that the given answer matches the given problem.

Comment: As for the generalized problem where you have $k$ distinct stars and $\ell$ distinct squares and you choose $t$ total, you would have $\binom{k+\ell}{t}-\binom{k}{t}$ just as you did.  If you ask how many subsets of *any* size, then $2^k\cdot (2^\ell - 1)$

Answer (score 1):

First suppose the $3$ stamps purchased are distinct types . . .

The number of subsets of $3$ stamps with exactly one royal is
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{13}{2}=156$$
The number of subsets of $3$ stamps with two royals is
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{1}=13$$
Summing the results gives $156+13=169$.

But the problem doesn't specify that the $3$ stamps are distinct types, so that allows for more possibilities . . .

If all three stamps are the same type, that yields two more qualifying results.

So now the count is $169+2=171$.

If exactly two are the same type, we have some cases . . .

If the two same-type ones are royals, and the third one is also royal, the count is
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}=2$$
If the two same-type ones are royals, and the third one is non-royal, the count is
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{13}{1}=26$$
If the two same-type ones are non-royals, the count is
$$\binom{13}{1}\binom{2}{1}=26$$
Summing the results gives $171+2+26+26=225$.

Comment: Thanks so much.  The problem told me that there are only 2 royals in the set of 15 stamps, and that I purchased 3 stamps with at least one being a royal.  Because of this I could not have purchased 3 stamps that were the same.  There aren't 3 royals.

Comment: But that makes me question . . . if the problems states that the post office has 15 types of stamps, can't I assume that they are distinct?  I'm new to this, so I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure, the $15$ _types_ are distinct. But surely, the post office has _quantities_ of each type, so when you buy $3$ stamps, unless the problem _specifies_ that you must buy $3$ distinct types, there's nothing to stop you from buying $3$ stamps, with some types more than once.

Answer (score 1):

There are 15 types of stamps. The number of multisets consisting of 3 stamps is $\binom{15+3-1}{3}$. (Note that we are allowed to buy more than one of the same type of stamp.) The number of multisets consisting of 3 stamps, none of which are royals, is $\binom{13+3-1}{3}$. Thus, the number of multisets consisting of 3 stamps, such that at least one of the stamps is a royal, is
$$
\binom{15+3-1}{3} - \binom{13+3-1}{3} = 225.
$$

I bet there's a typo in the answer you were given, and it was supposed to say $225$.